# Travis conditional deployment: deploy script with regexp for branch skipped with error `branch not permitted`

Tags: regex, deployment, continuous-integration, conditional-statements, travis-ci

I have specified multiple deploy script providers. One which is expected to run, but skipped is:

```
- provider: script
  skip_cleanup: true
  script: curl -sL https://git.io/goreleaser | bash -s -- --rm-dist --skip-publish
  verbose: true
  on:
    condition: "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME = linux"
    branches:
      only:
      - /^release\/.*$/
    go: 1.11.x
```

- Last three deploys are only on master branch, so its right to skip them.
- The first deploy which is on all branches matching regexp: /^release/.*$/ should run for this branch release/2.1.5. However it’s skipping this deploy too.

Can someone point why the release branch deploy is skipped in this case? I want the first deploy to run on linux and release branches only like: release/2.1.5.

Travis build: https://travis-ci.org/leopardslab/dunner/jobs/560593148

Travis Config file: https://github.com/leopardslab/dunner/blob/172a4c5792b0a8389556cc8ee4f690dc73fafb6e/.travis.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the deploy script conditionally, say only on branches matching a regular expression like release branches as `^release\/.*$`, use condition field and concatenate multiple conditions using &&. The `branch` or `branches` field does not support regexp.

If `branch` or `branches` field is not specified, travis assumes its on master branch(or default branch). So be sure to include `all_branches: true` line in travis config.

You can access current branch name using travis env variable `$TRAVIS_BRANCH`.

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: bash myscript.sh
    verbose: true
    on:
      all_branches: true
      condition: $TRAVIS_BRANCH =~ ^release\/.*$ && $TRAVIS_OS_NAME = linux
```